# Python script to iterate over text file infinitely

Tags: python

Need help trying to make this script run infinitely line by line from beginning to EOF and back to same process.
Here is the code.

```
with open('views.txt', 'r') as f:   
    
    if f == EOFError:
               
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        for x, line in enumerate(f):
            line.strip()
            
            link = r'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}'.format(line)

            wb.register('chrome',None,wb.BackgroundBrowser(
                                    "C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            wb.get('chrome').open(link, new=0, autoraise=True)
            # time.sleep(randint(200,350))
            time.sleep(randint(10, 13))
            os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
            time.sleep(randint(5,7))
                

    if f != EOFError:
        for x, line in enumerate(f):
            line.strip()
            
            link = r'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}'.format(line)

            wb.register('chrome',None,wb.BackgroundBrowser(
                                    "C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            wb.get('chrome').open(link, new=0, autoraise=True)
            # time.sleep(randint(200,350))
            time.sleep(randint(10, 13))
            os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
            time.sleep(randint(5,7))
                
                            
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you just put it in a [while loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm#:~:text=The%20loop%20iterates%20while%20the,a%20single%20block%20of%20code.)?

Comment: Please update your question with the modifications you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python you would do this:

```
while 1:
    for line in open('views.txt').readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        link = r'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}'.format(line)
        ...
        os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
        time.sleep(randint(5,7))
```

Comment: OMG that solved it you are super awsome thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to run infinitely, you can put the whole script inside a while loop.

```
while True:
    your code here
```

Comment: i tried but it still breaks at the EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Do It With While Loop!

```
with open('views.txt', 'r') as f:   
    while True:
        if f == EOFError:
                   
            f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
            for x, line in enumerate(f):
                line.strip()
                
                link = r'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}'.format(line)

                wb.register('chrome',None,wb.BackgroundBrowser(
                                        "C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
                wb.get('chrome').open(link, new=0, autoraise=True)
                # time.sleep(randint(200,350))
                time.sleep(randint(10, 13))
                os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
                time.sleep(randint(5,7))
                    

        if f != EOFError:
            for x, line in enumerate(f):
                line.strip()
                
                link = r'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}'.format(line)

                wb.register('chrome',None,wb.BackgroundBrowser(
                                        "C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
                wb.get('chrome').open(link, new=0, autoraise=True)
                # time.sleep(randint(200,350))
                time.sleep(randint(10, 13))
                os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
                time.sleep(randint(5,7))
```

I deleted the `else:` part because it doesn't do anything.